# Can the DLC's for destiny be shared between two accounts on ps3?

Tags: ps3, destiny

I was wondering if the downloadable content for destiny can be shared between two different accounts on a PlayStation 3?

Answer (score 2):

From the product's description: 
[image]

Most PS3 downloaded content can be shared by other accounts on the same console where it was downloaded, as long as it's one of the [two activated consoles associated with the downloading account](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps3/current/accountinfo/systemactivation.html). There are some rare exceptions, for example, DLC for Dungeon Siege III the game Final Fight Double impact is available for the purchasing account only.

The other exceptions are avatars which are tied to one account and one-time content like in-game cash/loot boxes which are tied to the account who purchased them only.

Answer (score 1):

Anything purchasable can never be shared between accounts. It sort of makes sense for them. They would lose a lot of money if it was possible...

Comment: You definitely used to be able to 'share' call of duty maps dlc by signing into someone else's account and downloading it once, not sure if that's a valid option or if it still works though.

Comment: @ConnorLSW You used to, but only use it offline I think

Comment: I played the map packs online, unless my memory is really failing me, either way I think a proper source for this would be worthwhile just for clarification, "there's no official method of content sharing" is a valid answer though